# How to structure duplicate content in Laravel manyToMany relation

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, laravel-8

I have the following list of criteria for about 30 different activities:

```
 activity A
 sortorder  criteria
 1          abcd
 2          eftg
 3          kliu
 4          vdrs
 5          xgwe

 Activity B
 sortorder  criteria
 1          shsh
 2          kliu (same as 3 in A)
 3          swdd
 4          vdrs
 5          abcd (same as 1 in A)
 6          dehd

 Activity C
 sortorder  criteria
 1          shsh
 2          abcd (same as 3 in A & 5 in B)
 3          swdd
 4          dehd (same as 6 in B)
```

These data needs to be organized in 2 mysql tables Activities & Criteria (where the 4 letters above are a full sentence in reality).  For obvious reason the similar sentences (kliu, abcd & dehd) can only have one instance in the criteria table.

At some stage, a new table Codes needs to be populated by an activity with all the criteria attached to it.  Activity A is not a problem.  Activity B could be composed with its 6 criteria if there were encoded as manyToMany relation and a pivot table.  That is what I have been doing.

```
$activity->allcriteria->orderBy('sortorder')->pluck('body')->join("\n");
```

The problem is that the criteria need to be ordered by sortorder and in the above option that info is missing as the records B2, B5, C2 & C4 do not exist in the Criteria table in the option above.  So I added these missing records as:

```
 Activity B
 sortorder  criteria
 2          id of 3A
 5          id of 1A

 Activity C
 sortorder  criteria
 2          id of 3A
 4          id of 6B
```

In order to create the correct list of criteria (unique and shared in the correct order, I am using the following code... It works but I found it a bit cumbersome.

```
 Criteria::where('activity','=','B')->orderBy('sortorder')->get();
 foreach($allCriteria as $criteria) {
 // if criteria is shared (body = id of parent)
 if (is_numeric($criteria->body)) { 
     $parent = Criteria::where('id','=',$criteria->body)->first();
     $sc_body .= $parent->body."\n";
 // unique criteria
 } else {
     $sc_body .= $criteria->body."\n";
 }
```

Is their a better way to structure that in mysql & Laravel?

UPDATE

I added the sortorder field in the pivot table and updated the model Activity

```
    public function allcriteria()
      {
           return $this->belongsToMany(Criteria::class)->withPivot('sortorder')->orderByPivot('sortorder');
      }
```

1/ The ordering works fine and I can get the field sortorder from the pivot table in a collection with...

```
 $criteria = $thisActivity->allcriteria()->get();

 $criteria->pivot->sortorder;
```

2/ Then when I edit the activity and display all the criteria as checkboxes in the webform, the values of the sortorder field are automatically detached/attached to update the pivot table in the ActivityController update function.

```
 $activity->allcriteria()->where('id',$activity->id)->detach();
  $activity->allcriteria()->attach(request('criteria'));
```

3/ The next step is to find a way to re-order the criteria...

Comment: [Does this help?](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/ordering-many-to-many-relations)

Comment: No it does not because the pivot table does not contain the sort order.

Comment: You have described a many-to-many relationship and the need to order that relationship. The order should be stored as part of the many-to-many relationship!

Comment: @user1191247 Do you mean adding the sortorder field in the pivot table and than being able to retrieve it within the ManyToMany relation?  Do you have a working example?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. The previously commented link has an example, as does the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#retrieving-intermediate-table-columns) and [Ordering Queries Via Intermediate Table Columns](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#ordering-queries-via-intermediate-table-columns).

Comment: @user1191247 Sorry for the delay in following up... I have been away. I did follow your advice and I found the solution... easy!  Thank you!